# android hide fragment on pressing back button of fragmentActivity(FragmentB)

Tags: android, hide, fragment

hello all i am developing 1 app in to that [image: i have done this]

for displaying fragment 1 i have done this...(*works properly*)

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Scroller;

public class MainLayout extends LinearLayout {

    private static final int SLIDING_DURATION = 400;// 500
    private static final int QUERY_INTERVAL = 1;
    int mainLayoutWidth;
    public View menu;
    private View content;
    private static int menuRightMargin = 1;

    private enum MenuState {
        HIDING, HIDDEN, SHOWING, SHOWN,
    };

    private int contentXOffset;
    private MenuState currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDDEN;
    private Scroller menuScroller = new Scroller(this.getContext(),
            new EaseInInterpolator());
    private Runnable menuRunnable = new MenuRunnable();
    private Handler menuHandler = new Handler();
    int prevX = 0;
    boolean isDragging = false;
    int lastDiffX = 0;

    public MainLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MainLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        mainLayoutWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        menuRightMargin = mainLayoutWidth * 30 / 100;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        menu = this.getChildAt(0);
        content = this.getChildAt(1);
        content.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return MainLayout.this.onContentTouch(v, event);
            }
        });
        menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right,
            int bottom) {
        if (changed) {
            LayoutParams contentLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) content
                    .getLayoutParams();
            contentLayoutParams.height = this.getHeight();
            contentLayoutParams.width = this.getWidth();
            LayoutParams menuLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) menu
                    .getLayoutParams();
            menuLayoutParams.height = this.getHeight();
            menuLayoutParams.width = this.getWidth() - menuRightMargin;
        }
        menu.layout(left, top, right - menuRightMargin, bottom);
        content.layout(left + contentXOffset, top, right + contentXOffset,
                bottom);

    }

    public void toggleMenu() {

        if (currentMenuState == MenuState.HIDING
                || currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWING)
            return;

        switch (currentMenuState) {
        case HIDDEN:
            currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWING;
            menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            menuScroller.startScroll(0, 0, menu.getLayoutParams().width, 0,
                    SLIDING_DURATION);
            break;
        case SHOWN:
            currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDING;
            menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0, -contentXOffset, 0,
                    SLIDING_DURATION);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);
        this.invalidate();
    }
    public void toggleMenu1() {

        if (currentMenuState == MenuState.HIDING
                || currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWING)
            return;

        switch (currentMenuState) {
        /*case HIDDEN:
            currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWING;
            menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            menuScroller.startScroll(0, 0, menu.getLayoutParams().width, 0,
                    SLIDING_DURATION);
            break;*/
        case SHOWN:
            currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDING;
            menuScroller.startScroll(30, 0, -30, 0,
                    SLIDING_DURATION);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);
        this.invalidate();
    }

    protected class MenuRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            boolean isScrolling = menuScroller.computeScrollOffset();
            adjustContentPosition(isScrolling);
        }
    }

    private void adjustContentPosition(boolean isScrolling) {
        int scrollerXOffset = menuScroller.getCurrX();

        content.offsetLeftAndRight(scrollerXOffset - contentXOffset);

        contentXOffset = scrollerXOffset;
        this.invalidate();
        if (isScrolling)
            menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);
        else
            this.onMenuSlidingComplete();
    }

    private void onMenuSlidingComplete() {
        switch (currentMenuState) {
        case SHOWING:
            currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWN;
            break;
        case HIDING:
            currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDDEN;
            menu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
        default:
            return;
        }
    }

    protected class EaseInInterpolator implements Interpolator {
        @Override
        public float getInterpolation(float t) {
            return (float) Math.pow(t - 1, 5) + 1;
        }

    }


    public boolean isMenuShown() {
        return currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWN;
    }

    public boolean onContentTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (currentMenuState == MenuState.HIDING
                || currentMenuState == MenuState.SHOWING)
            return false;
        int curX = (int) event.getRawX();
        int diffX = 0;

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            prevX = curX;
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if (!isDragging) {
                isDragging = true;
                menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            diffX = curX - prevX;
            if (contentXOffset + diffX <= 0) {
                diffX = -contentXOffset;
            } else if (contentXOffset + diffX > mainLayoutWidth
                    - menuRightMargin) {
                diffX = mainLayoutWidth - menuRightMargin - contentXOffset;
            }
            content.offsetLeftAndRight(diffX);
            contentXOffset += diffX;
            this.invalidate();

            prevX = curX;
            lastDiffX = diffX;
            return true;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d("MainLayout.java onContentTouch()", "Up lastDiffX "
                    + lastDiffX);

            if (lastDiffX > 0) {
                currentMenuState = MenuState.SHOWING;
                menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0,
                        menu.getLayoutParams().width - contentXOffset, 0,
                        SLIDING_DURATION);
            } else if (lastDiffX < 0) {
                currentMenuState = MenuState.HIDING;
                menuScroller.startScroll(contentXOffset, 0, -contentXOffset, 0,
                        SLIDING_DURATION);
            }
            menuHandler.postDelayed(menuRunnable, QUERY_INTERVAL);
            this.invalidate();
            isDragging = false;

            prevX = 0;
            lastDiffX = 0;
            return true;

        default:
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
    public void hideMenu() {
    }


}
```

Now in Fragment B that extends FragmentActivity. on pressing BackButton of FragmentB i want to hide fragmentA how i can do this?

Answer (score 1):

I dont't see any fragments in your code, only Views. But if there is other part of code where you work with fragments you can do something like this on your FragmentActivity class:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (fragmentAIsShown) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                .beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.remove(fragmentManager
                .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content));
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    } else
        //go to previous activity
}
```

Also if you try to create SlidingMenu with fragments, you should take a look on this https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html .